# How to read a string in tcl using split with the last character?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to read the following text printing each string before ;

```
0:1:2:3;
1:2:0;
10:13:15;
```

I wrote the following code

```
foreach {line} [split [read $lFile] \n] {
   lassign [split $line ;] a
   puts $a
}
```

But the output is the same string. I want the string before ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl, semicolon marks the end of a command line, as such, you are actually doing `split $line` and not `split $line ;`. You will have to quote the `;` for it to work:

```
foreach {line} [split [read $lFile] \n] {
   lassign [split $line ";"] a
   puts $a
}
```

Or using braces:

```
foreach {line} [split [read $lFile] \n] {
   lassign [split $line {;}] a
   puts $a
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use double-quotes, since that encourages highlighting “like a string”. Also, `\;` would work, as would a number of other more obscure options.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
set a [regsub {;.*} $a ""]
```

or, assuming no text after the semicolon

```
set a [string trimright $a ";"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is the same string because you have a mistake in the `foreach` (as it was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667652/how-to-parse-a-text-file-in-tcl-using-separators/31667773#31667773)). Though, you don't have to use `foreach`. You can read file line by line using `while` loop.

```
set file [open lFile.txt r];

while {![eof $file]} {
    gets $file line;
    lassign [split $line ";"] splittedFile;
    puts stdout $splittedFile;
}
```

Or in other words, as long as file has not reached its end (`![eof $file]`), split file and print it to standard output.